# Cannot install VMware Workstation 7.0.0 on Dell inspiron 506S 

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

I want to install VMware Workstation on Windows 7, but there is no response after clicking the .exe file.

Is there a configuration I need to change before installing VMware on Windows 7?

- [Dell Inspiron 506S](http://www1.ap.dell.com/in/en/home/desktops/inspiron-560s/pd.aspx?refid=inspiron-560s&cs=indhs1&s=dhs)
- Windows 7 Home Premium

Answer (score 1):

Recommend looking at Virtualbox.  Runs VMWare images, faster, is free and scriptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install VMWare Workstation 5, it will work with your configuration.